# Max Word Size as a Function of Number of Words

Tags: statistics, computational-complexity

I want to describe the relationship between largest word length, `l`, and the number of words in a set, `n`.

Example:

- For the set of words `{"the", "large", "rock"}`, the largest word length is l = 5
- For `{"ten", "two", "cat"}`, the largest word length is l = 3
- For `{"a", "Mathematics"}`, the largest word length is l = 11

Can `l` be approximated as a function of `n`? **How is `l` related to `n`?**

If `n` were allowed to be very large, `l` would obviously be the length of the largest word in the English language. If `n` were limited to 1, `l` would obviously be the average size of all words. Intuition tells me that choosing more words gives me a statistically better chance of requiring a more buckets, but I can't explain why.

*I am not sure whether this question belongs on StackOverflow or Mathematics. This is not a homework problem. It came up in [an answer I posted over on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22230239/3224483).*

Comment: we need a distibution for length of each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first of all we have a fixed fnite set of words $A$. To each word there is an associated length.

for a subset of size $n$ the number of boxes is the maximum value of the length of those $n$ boxes. First of all notice that the relationship depends on the intitial fixed set. (In our case is is the set of words in the english language,so $A$=set of english words).

if we take a set of $n$ letter then the expected value $b$ of buckets is the sum of all of the maximum value of each pair of words divided by the number of pairs of words in the dictionary.

In general for a given $n$ the expected value $l$ of buckets is the sum of the maximum value of all the subsets of $n$ words divided by the number of subsets of $n$ words (denoted $\binom{A}{k}$the size of the set is $\binom{|A|}{k}$).

Comment: How is it that you managed to answer this question 20 days after I asked it right while I was in the middle of editing it?! I am sincerely sorry, but I changed the variable names while you were writing this in an effort to simplify the question. Should I change them back, or do you want to change yours? I also don't reference buckets any more.

Comment: No problem, I adjusted the answer to your variables